# Undefined variable's error when expected to have passed the content of variable

Tags: plugin-development

I implemented a simple class like:

```
class my_form {

        private $error_message;

        function __construct()
        {
            add_shortcode('my_form_custom', array($this, 'show_custom_form'));
        }

        function registration_template_form() {
        ?>              
            <div class="popup_canvas_container">            
                <form id="my_form" class="my_form" method="post" action="<?php echo esc_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>">
                    <p><label for="first_field">Field1:</label>&nbsp;<input type="text" name="first_field" id="first_field" value="<?php echo(isset($_POST['first_field']) ? $_POST['first_field'] : null); ?>" required /></p>
                    [...]
                    <div class="confirmation_box">
                        <p><button name="post_form" id="post_form" type="submit"><?php _e('Submit', 'my_form_textdomain'); ?></button></p>                      
                    </div>
                </form>
                <div id="messages_box" class="messages_box">
                    <p><div id="message_label"></div></p>
                </div>              
            </div>          
            
        <?  
        }                   
                    
        function form_validation() {
            if ( strlen($this->first_field) < 4 ) { 
                $error_message = 'Too short!';
                return false;
            }
        }
                    
        function save_to_db() {         
            if ( !$this->form_validation() ) {
                ?>                   
                    <script language="javascript">$("#message_label").text("<?php echo $error_message; ?>"); $('#messages_box').dialog();</script>
                <?php
            } else {    
            }
        }
                    
        function show_custom_form() {
            ob_start():
            
            if (isset($_POST['post_form'])) {
                $this->save_to_db();
            }
            
            $this->show_template_form();
            
            return ob_get_clean();
        }
}
```

and , as like as I found almost everywhere on Google, to pass content's variable to the message box div with jquery and I just did an echo so then I should show the error message displaying a dialog message.
But I keep getting in Console Log this error :

```
<script language="javascript">$("#message_label").text("<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: error_message in <b>..../my_form.php</b> on line <b>108</b><br />
"); $('#messages_box').dialog();</script>
```

at this point what would be the right way to pass variable's content to the div?  Thanks in advance! Cheers, Luigi

edit: if I implement using passing function values as like:

```
class my_form {

        private $first_field;
        public $error_message;      

        function __construct()
        {
            add_shortcode('my_form_custom', array($this, 'show_custom_form'));
        }

        function registration_template_form() {
        ?>              
            <div class="popup_canvas_container">            
                <form id="my_form" class="my_form" method="post" action="<?php echo esc_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>">
                    <p><label for="first_field">Field1:</label>&nbsp;<input type="text" name="first_field" id="first_field" value="<?php echo(isset($_POST['first_field']) ? $_POST['first_field'] : null); ?>" required /></p>
                    [...]
                    <div class="confirmation_box">
                        <p><button name="post_form" id="post_form" type="submit"><?php _e('Submit', 'my_form_textdomain'); ?></button></p>                      
                    </div>
                </form>
                <div id="messages_box" class="messages_box">
                    <p><div id="message_label"></div></p>
                </div>              
            </div>          
            
        <?  
        }                   
                    
        function form_validation() {
            if ( strlen($this->first_field) < 4 ) { 
                //$error_message = 'Too short!';
                //return false;
                
                return WP_Error('first_field_length', 'Too short. At least 4 characters is required.' );
            }
        }
                    
        function save_to_db() {         
            if ( !$this->form_validation() ) {
                ?>                   
                    <script language="javascript">$("#message_label").text("<?php echo $this->form_validation()->get_error_message(); ?>"); $('#messages_box').dialog();</script>
                <?php
            } else {    
            }
        }
                    
        function show_custom_form() {
            ob_start():
            
            if (isset($_POST['post_form'])) {
                $this->save_to_db();
            }
            
            $this->show_template_form();
            
            return ob_get_clean();
        }
}
```

then it would pass the message but instead to see dialog appearing it shows the message on the layout just right after entry_content's layout div when it should pass inside dialog's div template message box indeed.... that's why I tried with passing a variable...

Comment: In your `save_to_db()` method you do not have `$error_message` defined. Why not return that from `form_validation()`?

Comment: I do not believe this is a WordPress question, but a generic PHP question. **Generic PHP questions go on stackoverflow**

Comment: @Howdy_McGee ....I forgot to write down I already declared that $error_message as private class variable.... that's why I don't understand the reason it gives me back that undefined variable error because it's declared in fact as private class variable so it should be available from all methods and functions in the class....

Comment: @TomJNowell I know it'd be a generic php question , I just asked here because looking on internet and also on stackoverflow , that "echo $error_message" 's syntax looks like right so I thought it could be because some uncompatibility with wordpress engine....

Comment: @Luigino, "when it should pass inside dialog's div template message box" - that sounded like a generic JS issue, and it's probably because you echo the script (in `save_to_db()`) before the elements are attached to the DOM, i.e. before `show_template_form()` is called. Check the *browser's* console and see if there are any errors relevant to your form/dialog.

Comment: @Luigino there is no such thing as the _WordPress engine_, WordPress is just PHP code that runs in PHP, much like the code you're writing. Classes and variables are a part of PHP, and WordPress could not change that even if it wanted to. A lot of the problems you are encountering here are general programming problems that you would encounter in lots of other programming languages. Infact they would generate compiler errors in classic languages such as C++.

Comment: Problems such as misunderstanding local scope, the difference between `$var` and `$this->var`, functions that sometimes return values but sometimes don't return values, using variables that don't exist yet, etc, all problems that are covered in the official PHP docs for classes and elsewhere

Comment: I've closed this as it has very little to do with WordPress. I believe you should revisit the basics rather than brute forcing your way through to a working piece of code. It will save you a lot of time, but also it's not in this stacks scope. A good guide is that if the question does not require or involve WordPress expertise to solve then it's not a good fit, even if it just happens to be on a WordPress site. You don't need to limit yourself to just WP developers to get general PHP help

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the code ignores scope, a fundamental programming concept.

This scope:

```php
        function form_validation() {
...
                $error_message = 'Too short!';
...
        }
```

and this scope:

```php
        function save_to_db() {         
...           
                    ... echo $error_message;...
        }
```

Are not the same. It would be unreasonable and illogical to expect it to transfer over. When you assign `$error_message` a value int he `form_validation` function that variable only exists inside `form_validation()`. Once that function finishes executing there are no longer references to the variable and it can be garbage collected.

When `save_to_db` happens it is in a different scope, so even if the `error_message` from `form_validation` still existed, it would not be the same `$error_message` variable.

This is why we have the `global` keyword, but importantly, objects can hold state, aka class member variables. It's one of the main reasons classes exist in the first place, and for some reason it was not used. Classes are not inherently *"better"*, they're a tool, and if all you wanted was a global variable you could access anywhere, then you should have used functions instead, or return values.

The irony is that you've already used the solution, and done it in a way that would generate exactly the same warning:

```php
if ( strlen($this->first_field) < 4 ) {
```

Nowhere in the code gives `first_field` a value, or define it in any way. You have to declare that something exists before you use it, either by defining it or by giving it a value. You can't pull things out of thin air.

Further reading:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php

Comment: I edited my initial post with a variation returning wp's function value but it doesn't behave as expected

Comment: your update doesn't make sense, you returned a WP_Error object but then if the form validates you don't return anything ( I'd expect a `true` to say yes it validates? ), as a result `null` is returned when it's valid. Then, in the code that uses that function you don't check if it's an error object, and then you tried to use it as if it's a string error message, even though it is not a string, it's a WP_Error object. You've revealed that you have a class member variable with the same name but for some reason you've not used it and instead created brand new local variables with the same name